# Possessive Ambiguity: sharing a house

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage, ambiguity

Could this:

> Jason shared Michael's house.

be an acceptable shortened version of this:

> Jason shared Michael's house with Michael.

?

Comment: Suspiciously similar to two recently **deleted** questions: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106002/subtleties-of-verb-share http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106069/ambiguity-about-share

Answer (score 1):

Yes, though the wording is ambiguous. In your example, the 'with Michael' is implied. I would suggest rewording to

> Jason and Michael shared a house.

to remove the ambiguity and keep the sentence from getting bulky and awkward.

Comment: But "Jason shared Michael's house" does not necessarily mean Michael lived there with him. If you want to say both that Michael was the owner of the house AND that he lived there with Jason, you need to say something like "Jason and Michael shared Michael's house."

Comment: As I said, though correct, it is ambiguous. Your version, however, is probably the best, as it contains all the relevant information without any ambiguity or verbiage.

Comment: At least in spoken Australian English, _Michael's house_ does not necessarily imply ownership, only prior occupancy. "Where are you living next term? I am moving into Michael's house." might convey that there is a leased house shared by up to half a dozen students of whom one (Michael) is known to both of the speakers.

Comment: That's true in American English as well, though without context, the possessive should probably be used to assume ownership. (Even in your example, I'd argue that ownership is still being claimed, but at an emotional, rather than legal, level.) You bring up an interesting point.